# changing the column nullable by a specific value from a column

Tags: oracle

```
column x (Not NULL)          | column z 
1............................| P
0............................| T
```

I got a check constraint : column x in (1, 0), so the column only accept value 1 and 0
what I want which is really weird (*I don't want a procedure or a trigger*). I want a way like constraints to change the nullable of the column `z` by the value that the column `x` have

example:

- if column `x` has value of 1 column `z` should be nullable,
- if column `x` have value of 0 column `z` should be Not null with default N

Why do I want that? I am using oracle and sybase, the problem in sybase if I add column with out specifiying if null or not , automatically it will be not null(add test varchar(12) <-- this will be Null in sybase by default and null by oracle , so by that column I want to specify if its syabse or oracle)

Maybe a procedure will be better , but I am searching if there is another way for my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with a check constraint for integrity:

```
ALTER TABLE <table> ADD CONSTRAINT chk_x_z CHECK (X = 1 OR Z IS NOT NULL)
```

This will make sure that your business rule is always enforced.

You will need either a procedure or a trigger to implement your custom `default N`.

Comment: can I write check ( column x = 1 and column z = a )?

Comment: It is not clear from your questions what values are accepted for `(x,z)`. You must write a constraint that evaluates to `TRUE` or `NULL` for all rows and evaluates to `FALSE` for all forbidden values.

Comment: WELL THATS WHAT I DID THAK YOU VINCENT